# how to find locations of the substring given by the recognition sequence in the genome

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

i want locations of the substring given by the recognition sequence in the genome. wrote a function which pass through the sequence and store the indices where we match the recognition sequence but its returning empty conatiner.
the sequence looks like

```
ATCGGCGCGCGCGCGTATATATATATATATAGGCGCGCGCGCGCGTATATATATATATAGCGGCGCGCGCGCG
```

```
def restriction_sites(seq, recog_seq):
    """Find the indices of all restriction sites in a sequence."""
    #here variable "seq" contains fasta sequence and "recog_seq" contains recognition sequence
    # Initialize list of restriction sites
    sites = []

    # Check every substring for a match
    for i in range(len(seq) - len(recog_seq)):
        if seq[i:i+len(recog_seq)] == recog_seq:
            sites.append(i)

    return sites
```

when i run it like this:

```
print('HindIII:', restriction_sites(seq, 'AAGCTT'))
```

it shows me empty:

```
[]
```

i want output like this

```
HindIII: [23129, 25156, 27478, 36894, 37458, 37583, 44140]
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what does not work without some sample data. Just one thing, you're _not_ checking every substring: your loop doesn't reach the last one. It should be `for i in range(len(seq) - len(recog_seq) + 1):`

Answer (score 2):

Your original function works. It returned you a blank list because your example seq has not `'AAGCTT'`. For instance, it returned `[15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55]` to me for `"TATA"`.

I could recommend use `re` for matching sites. That looks more explicit:

```
import re
from typing import *

def restriction_sites(seq: str, recog_seq: str) -> List[int]:
    return [match.start() for match in re.finditer(fr"(?={recog_seq})", seq)]
```

Comment: with re.finditer it gives error

Comment: @Vicky Which error?

Comment: return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What types do you use for a seq & a template?

Comment: @Vicky I have just updated my answer because up to this point it found only non-overlapping matches that is not acceptable for search of a recognition site.

Comment: both seq and template are lists

Comment: As something like this: `['A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'G']`?

Comment: the "seq" is list which looks like this "ATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTAAAAAAAAAAAGCACGACGACAGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCAGTACGTTTTTTTAGTCCCCATTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCCCCCAT" and recog seq is list which looks like this "TTTTTT, TTAAA, TTCCC"

Comment: @Vicky But they are strings! What do you put as arguments specifically? What is the result of `type(seq)` & `type(recog_seq)`? Why does your recog_seq string have commas? Do you want to check several templates per time?

Comment: yes i want to check several templates and  result of type(seq) & type(recog_seq) is list

Comment: recog seq is list which looks like this ['TTTTTT', 'TTAAA', 'TTCCC']

Comment: OK, I got the thing with templates. You should have noted this in question that there are several templates, not one sequence. Moreover, your function takes only one template, so it was confounding. But is seq a list of what? Seclude nucleotides? One more point, your original function works. It returned you a blank list because your example seq has not `'AAGCTT'`. For instance, it returned `[15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55]` to me for `"TATA"`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be this

```
s = "ATCGGCGCGCGCGCGTATATATATATATATAGGCGCGCGCGCGCGTATATATATATATAGCGGCGCGCGCGCG"
r = "TATA"
HindIII = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+4] == r:
        HindIII.append(i)
print(HindIII)
```